# Jython : Issues executing XSLT

Tags: xslt, jython, exslt, jython-2.5

Ignoring identation, below Jython code when executed from command line produces, output with self-closing tags(No data), as shown in the picture below

```
from java.io import *
import javax.xml
from java.io import StringReader, StringWriter
from javax.xml.transform import Transformer, TransformerFactory
from javax.xml.transform.stream import StreamResult, StreamSource

def obtainservicexslts():

print "In obtainservicexslts"    
print
source_xform_xml = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<service-config>
  <service path="/Market">
    <request>         
      <rule transform="local:///services/xslt/MarketRequest.xslt">Transform</rule>
    </request>
    <response>
      <rule transform="local:///services/xslt/MarketResponse.xslt">Transform</rule>          
    </response>        
  </service>
</service-config>"""

source_xform_xslt = """<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="xsltkey" match="/*/*/*/rule[contains(., 'Transform')]/@transform" use="."/>
<xsl:template match="/" mode="xsltname">
    <xsl:variable name="firstoutput">
        <xsl:call-template name="firstpass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="mutate">            
        <xsl:with-param name="pr" select="exsl:node-set($firstoutput)/*"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*" name="firstpass">
    <dpXsltTransforms>
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/rule[contains(., 'Transform')]/@transform[generate-id()
                                   = generate-id(key('xsltkey',.)[1])]">
            <transform-dpPath>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </transform-dpPath>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </dpXsltTransforms>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="mutate">
    <xsl:param name="pr"/>
    <services-xslt>            
        <xsl:for-each select="pr/transform-dpPath[contains(., 'local:///services/xslt/')]">
            <xslt-cognomen>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,24)"/>
            </xslt-cognomen>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </services-xslt>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>"""

try:
    transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(StreamSource(StringReader(source_xform_xslt)))
    output_buffer = StringWriter()       
    transformer.transform(StreamSource(StringReader(source_xform_xml)), StreamResult(output_buffer))
    print output_buffer.buffer.toString()        
    return output_buffer.buffer.toString()   
except:                
    raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obtainservicexslts()
```

[image: CommandLine Execution]

​If we take 'xml' and 'xslt' from the script ​, save as ​2 separate files and execute the transform in XMLSPY​, below output is observed

[image: XMLSPY Execution]

The output from XMLSPY is desired and I'm not able to replicate the same behavior using my code.

Another point to be noted, I have used  'exsl' as part of xslt. Not sure, if that matters

Did anybody encountered similar issue and how was it resolved?

Kindly throw some pointers

I'm open to adjust the code either in xslt or jython to get things done

Comment: Are the first and third template are just in there to confuse people? It seems those modes are never used. I get the right result with Saxon at http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZNQ or Xalan at http://xsltransform.net/gVhD8RS so it doesn't seem related to XSLT and Java. Not sure what goes wrong, what happens when you write Java code instead of Jython? Do you get the same result as with Jython?

Comment: @MartinHonnen , I didn't try in Java as I want to accomplish this in Jython only. Agree that first and third template never getting used. I need to fix that. Thanks for sharing Saxon and Xalan results. They are similar to XML SPY results. The problem is not with XSLT. It is with the way Jython is treating XML with XSLT

Comment: Inasmuch as Jython's default Transformer seems to be generating erroneous output, my first recommendation would be to engage a different, known-good Transformer.  If that is not an option then it appears to me that your best bet would be to try to simplify your XSLT in order to, perhaps, cut out the bit that the default Transformer is tripping over.

Comment: Simplifications / changes you could make include (\*) cut out the templates that aren't actually used; (\*) instead of using `generate-id()` to identify group exemplars, use node-set union and `count()`: ...`@transform[count(. | key('xsltkey',.)[1]) = 1]`.

Comment: Or we might speculate that your transformer doesn't like keys that match attribute nodes.  You could therefore try defining your key to instead match the element carrying the attribute, with corresponding adjustments elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , as changing Jython's default Transformer was not an option to me, I had tried your [node-set union] and [count()] and it worked. Thank you so much and if possible, could you please explain what could have been the issue with [generate-id()]

Comment: @Kpulaparthi, I can only speculate about the `generate-id()` failure mode, but my guess was and is that it returns different values for what should have been the same attribute nodes, so that your ID comparisons always failed.  That the alternative I suggested works tells me that the union operator does recognize when the two expressions produce the same node, so I think the problem is likely specific to and localized in `generate-id()`.