# XML XSLT transformation using Jython

Tags: xml, xslt, jython, transformation

I'm trying to create a simple Jython script that does an xslt transformation.

Input xml :

```
<service-config>
      <service>
        <request>
          <rule transform="local:///services/xslt/RequestMapping.xslt">Framework-Policy-Transform</rule>
        </request>
        <response>
          <rule transform="local:///services/xslt/ResponseMapping.xslt">Framework-Policy-Transform</rule>
        </response>
      </service>
    </service-config>
```

XSLT -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="xsltkey" match="/*/*/*/rule[contains(., 'Framework-Policy-Transform')]/@transform" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/" mode="xsltname">
        <xsl:variable name="firstoutput">
            <xsl:call-template name="firstpass"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mutate">            
            <xsl:with-param name="pr" select="exsl:node-set($firstoutput)/*"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*" name="firstpass">
        <dpXsltTransforms>
            <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/rule[contains(., 'Framework-Policy-Transform')]/@transform[generate-id()
                                       = generate-id(key('xsltkey',.)[1])]">
                <transform-dpPath>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </transform-dpPath>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </dpXsltTransforms>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mutate">
        <xsl:param name="pr"/>
        <services-xslt>            
            <xsl:for-each select="pr/transform-dpPath[contains(., 'local:///services/xslt/')]">
                <xslt-cognomen>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,24)"/>
                </xslt-cognomen>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </services-xslt>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dpXsltTransforms>
   <transform-dpPath>local:///services/xslt/RequestMapping.xslt</transform-dpPath>
   <transform-dpPath>local:///services/xslt/ResponseMapping.xslt</transform-dpPath>
</dpXsltTransforms>
```

Jython script -

```
from java.io import *
import javax.xml
from javax.xml.transform import Transformer, TransformerFactory
from javax.xml.transform.stream import StreamResult, StreamSource
from xml.dom import minidom

def obtainservicexslts():


    source_xform_xml = """<service-config>
      <service>
        <request>
          <rule transform="local:///services/xslt/RequestMapping.xslt">Framework-Policy-Transform</rule>
        </request>
        <response>
          <rule transform="local:///services/xslt/ResponseMapping.xslt">Framework-Policy-Transform</rule>
        </response>
      </service>
    </service-config>"""

    source_xform_xslt = """<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="xsltkey" match="/*/*/*/rule[contains(., 'Framework-Policy-Transform')]/@transform" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/" mode="xsltname">
        <xsl:variable name="firstoutput">
            <xsl:call-template name="firstpass"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mutate">            
            <xsl:with-param name="pr" select="exsl:node-set($firstoutput)/*"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*" name="firstpass">
        <dpXsltTransforms>
            <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/rule[contains(., 'Framework-Policy-Transform')]/@transform[generate-id()
                                       = generate-id(key('xsltkey',.)[1])]">
                <transform-dpPath>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </transform-dpPath>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </dpXsltTransforms>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mutate">
        <xsl:param name="pr"/>
        <services-xslt>            
            <xsl:for-each select="pr/transform-dpPath[contains(., 'local:///services/xslt/')]">
                <xslt-cognomen>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,24)"/>
                </xslt-cognomen>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </services-xslt>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>"""

    try:
        transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(StreamSource(StringReader(source_xform_xslt)))
        output_buffer = StringWriter()       
        transformer.transform(StreamSource(StringReader(source_xform_xml)), StreamResult(output_buffer))
        print output_buffer.buffer.toString()        
        return output_buffer.buffer.toString()   
    except:                
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obtainservicexslts()
```

Actual output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dpXsltTransforms/>
```

Any thoughts on how to treat my input variable in the script as an XML instead of a string, which i assume is the reason for not transforming as i'd like to...?

Thanks for your time, in advance!

Comment: This is a pretty big question.  Why not construct the minimal program required to explore your suspicions?

Comment: I agree that it looks pretty big. But actually the question is quite simple. How to set an xml in a jython variable and read it as an xml instead of a string.

Comment: You may ignore the xslt for now. I just added these for reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572227/jython-issues-executing-xslt has the same code but by a different poster.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Bollinger for his answer in another post!

Here's his answer - 
The reason why this wasn't working was because the Transformer was tripping over the usage of generate-id().
So in order to identify group exemplars, use node-set union and count()

The line in the xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/rule[contains(., 'Framework-Policy-Transform')]/@transform[generate-id()
                                       = generate-id(key('xsltkey',.)[1])]">
```

needs to be changed to

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/rule[contains(., 'Framework-Policy-Transform')]/@transform[count(. | key('xsltkey',.)[1]) = 1]">
```

and the jython script works!